# Left Aligning Button Text in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am using the following code to create an `OutlinedButton` in Jetpack Compose:

```
OutlinedButton(
            colors = ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(Color.Transparent),
            border = BorderStroke(0.dp, Color.Transparent),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                               .background(
                color = Color.Transparent,
        shape = RectangleShape, // Oval shape

        //border = androidx.compose.ui.drawBorder(2.dp, Color.Red) // Border color and width
        ),
            onClick = {}
        ) {

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 0.dp, vertical = 0.dp),
                color = Color.Black,
                text = text,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Left,
                fontSize = 15.sp,
            )
        }
```

I tried using `TextAlign.Left` and `TextAlign.Start`. However, it always aligns in the center:

[image]

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Row inside Button

```
OutlinedButton(onClick = {  }, modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(48.dp)) {

        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            Text(text = "Button Text", textAlign = TextAlign.Start)

        }


    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm! Do you know how to left align and right align text simultaneously in a row?

Comment: You mean one text with left align and second text with right align right?

Comment: Yes! Here's my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77378105/left-and-right-align-text-simultaneously-inside-a-button-on-the-same-line-in-jet

Answer (score 1):

Use `fillMaxWidth()` on `Text` with alignment as `Left`.

```
@Composable
fun LeftAlignSample() {
    OutlinedButton(
        onClick = {},
    ) {
        Text(
            "Text",
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Left,
        )
    }
}
```