# OutlinedTextField shows up only once

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, jetpack

Here's my code for a form text field composable:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun FormTextFieldComponent(
    topText: String,
    initialText: String=""
) = Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(16.dp)
) {
    // Small Text at the top (dynamic content)

    var textState by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(initialText)) }

    OutlinedTextField(
        value = textState,
        onValueChange = {
            textState = it
        },
        label = { Text(topText) }
    )
}
```

However, it shows up only once with this code (only shows the first textfield):

```
FormTextFieldComponent("First Name", "Van")
Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(1.dp))
FormTextFieldComponent("Last Name", "Chen")
Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(1.dp))
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What's the parent composable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer is:
You are using `fillMaxSize()`, so when the first TextField is render, it fills all the screen, then the second one is rendering outside the screen.
So you should use `fillMaxWidth()` instead of `fillMaxSize()`

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(16.dp)
)
```

You can prove this using this code, wrapping one of the TextFields and scaling the 0.5 of the full size

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(0.5f)){
            FormTextFieldComponent(topText = "First Name", initialText = "Van")
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        FormTextFieldComponent(topText = "Last Name", initialText = "Chen")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(1.dp))
    }
}
```

[image: proving the first text field was using all the screen size]

Also as recommendation to have more control in the sizes, try to always put a `modifier` parameter to composable functions like this:

```
@Composable
fun FormTextFieldComponent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    topText: String,
    initialText: String=""
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp)
    ){ }
}
```

Is a good practice in order to modify this from the parent.

Answer (score 4):

There is two problem as I see:
1- if you only see one text field and no more views on the screen it is because your function matches the size of your whole view. change it to wrapcontentsize()
2- if you see some other view as well but your data is repetitive it is because you have not created a 'Key' for your text state.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun FormTextFieldComponent(
    key: String,
    topText: String,
    initialText: String=""
) = Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .wrapContentSize()
        .padding(16.dp)
) {
    var textState by remember(key) { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(initialText)) }

    OutlinedTextField(
        value = textState,
        onValueChange = {
            textState = it
        },
        label = { Text(topText) }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `fillMaxSize()` modifier.